# How to get info from textfield?

Tags: label, textfield

I am new to xcode. I Have a text field form, in this form i can type only numbers.
How i can get information from this text field to my label?

Comment: Can you show an example of code you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're developing for iOS?
[label setText:textField.text]; should do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation WorktimerViewController{
NSTimer *timer;
int MainInt;
int zarabotal;
int stavka; }

@synthesize price;
@synthesize donebutton;
@synthesize lave;




- (void)updateLabels
{
self.lave.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", zarabotal];

}
- (void) countup
{
MainInt += 1;
_second.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", MainInt];


}

- (void)StartTimer{
MainInt = 1;
timer = [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countup) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 zarabotal = stavka / MainInt;
[self updateLabels];

}
```